# Reinstall ubuntu on an existing ubuntu partition

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have a computer that is dual booted with Windows Vista and Ubuntu. I have had Ubuntu for a long time now and during that time I have learned how to use it by tinkering around with it. This, of course, has lead to some problems. I would like to somehow reinstall Ubuntu on the same partition but keep Windows intact.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can we assume Ubuntu is installed on a separate partition than Windows?  or did you install via Wubi to the Windows partition?

Comment: its installed on a separate partition. I did not use Wubi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the data on the Ubuntu partition, simply install over the top.

Boot from Ubuntu install CD as usual, then manually edit partitions. Delete the Ubuntu system partition and the swap partition. Go back and chose automatic install, and the partitioner should recreate fresh partitions for you in the same place.

Comment: i *don't* recommend deleting the partitions; just use the "manually edit" to set which partition is for root/swap, and have it format them.  same effect without unnecessarily altering the partition table.

Comment: so I should just format the ubuntu partition and reinstall ubuntu in the partition again?

Comment: @Codedude, yes. I suspect the installer will try and create new partitions for you if you don't delete the old ones. It's easy enough to set root and swap if you know what you're doing though (as quack says), but the partition editor is not the most friendly of interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

On a side note, I'd read up first on how to configure Grub to launch the Windows boot manager, or be very sure I install the grub boot loader on the partition instead of the MBR.

The default is to instll Grub on the MBR if I recall which would wipe out your windows boot loader and render it temporarily unbootable.

No biggy, but a hassle to fix and a heart attack waiting to happen if you're not expecting it :D